# Uploads going to the root of wp-content/uploads

Tags: uploads

I have an on-again, off-again client that I just did a Wordpress/plugins/theme update for. When I opened the uploads folder, I noticed that there is one year folder from 2014 and then all the images are at the root level of the uploads folder. I have checked the following for code that would control the upload.

1. functions.php
2. .htaccess
3. wp-config.php
4. Plugin list

I have not found anything that would indicate code that would by-pass the WordPress core function. What else should I check?

Comment: Are those uploads available in the media library? Are you sure this was done by code or a plugin? Could this just be user error?

Comment: Yes, the uploads are available in the Media Library. I did an upload to test that. My upload went to the root level of /wp-content/uploads. There are other recent uploads from this year.

The site is owned by a membership, volunteer group, which explains their on-again-off-again status. I can't see the person who is doing content management having enough knowledge to by-pass the default WordPress core function.

Answer (score 1):

What else to check?

First, deactivate all plugins and switch to a different theme. Then test uploads.
If its fixed reactivate plugins/theme one at a time until you find the culprit.

Next, you can check the database `options` table to see if the `upload_path` or `upload_url_path` have been altered, they should be blank.

Then, you would have to start checking the WP core files. Try reinstalling. If that doesn't work.

Nuke the whole thing and walk away... Or just leave it, if its still functions fine.